# Can an edge be solidified?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

An object consists of a single edge (two vertices). How can it be made visible when rendering? In other words, how can it be "solidified"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be converted into a curve ( Object Mode > <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > Curve from Mesh ) and then have its bevel and profile [modified](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html) in various ways

Comment: Although, personally, I'd like to be able to cap its ends without having to assign a bevel object?

Answer (score 1):

Two different options:

**Skin Modifier**

Used a lot in combination with the subdivision surface modifier to generate a base mesh to sculpt on. It also has an option to generate a rig to modify the 'pose' in a later stage.
[image]

**Wireframe Modifier**

The options in the modifier's panel are the closes to the Bevel modifier. This does the job, but personally I think you have less control over the generated volume.

[image]

Comment: Wireframe Modifier and Wireframe Node don't work in this case, they both need adjacent faces to work properly.